# DT::renderDataTable eliminates the 'Inf' (infinity) values while displaying

Tags: r, shiny, dt

R displays data table properly in the console:

[image: Data table]

But when rendering the table using shiny:DT package it doesn't show the 'Inf' values:

[image: Shiny table]

Is there any way to fix this problem ?

Here is the code that I have used:

```
output$diffgeneExp <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diffGeneExpTable_data(), options = list(scrollX = T))
 })
```

Comment: What does your browser say if you do inspect element and then hover over one of the empty cells?

Comment: @Dean - The browser shows this when I inspect the element: `<td class=" dt-right"></td>`

Comment: Try making any columns that have Inf into `numeric` instead of `integer`.  If they're already `numeric` then you might have to make them `character`.

Comment: @Dean - The columns with 'Inf' are already in numeric. I want to implement a slider to filter values below a cutoff. Converting 'Inf' to character may cause issues while implementing this slider because the variable would have a mix of numeric and chars if the convert 'Inf' to character.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that `Inf` in R isn't translating to the equivalent in JSON.

Comment: This seems like an issue with DT.

Comment: @Carl - Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Your best bet might be to filter, and then convert to character before sending to the table.

Comment: I agree with Carl.  There might be a way to fix it with CSS or something (I have no experience with Javascript, JSON, etc) but as an alternative to converting to character you could change your Inf values to arbitrarily large numbers

Comment: I have realized this issue logn time ago, and you just need to help me convince this guy https://github.com/jeroenooms/jsonlite/issues/94

Comment: See https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/536

Comment: @Carl unfortunately it seems like converting it to a character removes the potential for a meaningful numerical sort if you want that functionality.